# Как сделать, что бы при разрешении 1024 включалась горизонтальная прокрутка карусели?

Tags: javascript

Для bxslider нашел такой скрипт, необходимо что бы при разрешении от 1024 и меньше включалась горизонтальная прокрутка. Если прописываю вручную, то отрубается и вертикальная прокрутка.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        sliderResize();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        sliderResize();
    });

    function sliderResize() {
        var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
             mode: 'vertical',
             minSlides: 3,
             maxSlides: 10,
             slideWidth: 100,
             slideMargin: 5,
    });

    if ($(window).width()==1920 && $(window).width()>=1281) {
        slider.reloadSlider({
             minSlides: 4,
             maxSlides: 10,
    });
    } else if ($(window).width()<=1280) {
         slider.reloadSlider({
             minSlides: 3,
             maxSlides: 10,
        });
    };
 }
     function sliderResize() {
         var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
              mode: 'vertical',
              minSlides: 3,
              maxSlides: 10,
              slideWidth: 100,
              slideMargin: 5,
      });

    if ($(window).width()==1024 && $(window).width()>=481) {
        slider.reloadSlider({
              minSlides: 4,
              maxSlides: 10,
    });
    } else if ($(window).width()<=480) {
         slider.reloadSlider({
              minSlides: 3,
              maxSlides: 10,
     });
 };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно удалять и пересоздавать слайдер при изменении разрешения

```js
var slider = $('.bxslider');
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width()<=1024) {
      slider.bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
      });
    } else {
      slider.bxSlider({
        mode: 'vertical',
      });
    }
  });
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width()<=1024) {
      slider.destroySlider();
      slider.bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
      });
    } else {
      slider.destroySlider();
      slider.bxSlider({
        mode: 'vertical',
      });
    }
  });
```